# Graphics2D Cannot be serialized

Tags: java

Java:

How can I serialize Graphics2D? I am making a platformer game, and I want a saving/loading system, using serialization.

```
    java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D
```

It prints this Exception. Is there any way to have serialized Graphics2D?

Comment: You should focus on saving the state rather than the objects if your can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, instances of `Graphics2D` (and other classes that deal with graphics, sound, or networking) typically are not `Serializable`.  You should try to separate the data that you need to save from the code that handles the rendering.

If that's not possible then you should mark your `Graphics2D` field as `transient`.  That way the serialization system will skip over the `Graphics2D` field when saving it out.  Upon loading you can just set the `Graphics2D` field to be a new instance that you create manually.

Comment: Where do I put transient? Before to=he

Comment: You put `transient` in the definition of the field of type `Graphics2D` in the class you are serializing.

Comment: private void init() {
  
  image = new BufferedImage(
     WIDTH, HEIGHT,
     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
  g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
  
  running = true;
  
  rms = new RoomManager(this);
  
         }   
This yields an error, saying image is not seralizable. I have marked it as transient...

Comment: Both `image` and `g` must be marked as `transient`.  Also you should make sure that RoomManager does not have any fields that are non-`Serializable` (like direct references to `image` or `g`).

Comment: Sorry, I had another buffered image named `image`. I fixed it. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `createGraphics()` instead of `getGraphics()`? `getGraphics()` is maintained for backward compatibility, but its use is not recommended